# Foundation for Apps -> angular-scroll

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation-apps

I am trying to use angular-scroll (https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) with foundation for apps but it just will not scroll :(

Everything is getting loaded (all scripts), when i chick on the navigation for the scroll to nothing happens. When i take all the code out of the ui-view and have it as a sperate page it works, so i am thinking its something to do with routing?

All code i have used is from the example on angular-scroll @ https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll

here it is online -
http://www.medmedia.ie/ngTest/scroll

---

any help would be great

Cheers
Pierce

---

Here is the js & templete Page:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('application', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'duScroll',

    //foundation
    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations'
  ]);
    myApp.config(config)
    myApp.run(run)
 

  config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

  function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlProvider.otherwise('/scroll.html');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }

  function run() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }



myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $document){
    $scope.toTheTop = function() {
      $document.scrollTopAnimated(0, 5000).then(function() {
        console && console.log('You just scrolled to the top!');
      });
    }
    var section3 = angular.element(document.getElementById('section-3'));
    $scope.toSection3 = function() {
      $document.scrollToElementAnimated(section3);
    }
  }
).value('duScrollOffset', 30);



})();
```

```html
---
name: scroll
url: /scroll
animationIn: slideInRight
---

<div class="wrap" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#section-1" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-2" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section-3" du-smooth-scroll du-scrollspy>Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1>Angular.js Scrollspy Example</h1>
  <section id="section-1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet sausage tail capicola ground round hamburger ham hock. Short ribs pig andouille meatball, pastrami tri-tip fatback ham hock shank kielbasa swine. Rump pancetta jerky kielbasa doner beef ribs tongue hamburger strip steak drumstick andouille shoulder shank flank. Swine drumstick meatball pig beef sausage strip steak.</p>

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500/" alt="" />
  </section>

  <section id="section-2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Bacon strip steak ground round, tongue pastrami short ribs pork chop venison turducken sausage sirloin. Flank chicken pork chop capicola turkey turducken cow pork loin biltong meatball drumstick pancetta filet mignon ground round fatback. Ham hock jerky short ribs brisket. Meatloaf shoulder pork chop capicola, sirloin swine pig pork. Jerky ribeye hamburger pork loin sirloin kevin bresaola boudin chuck flank. Ham hock pork belly chicken jerky rump bresaola.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section-3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>Shank fatback pastrami short loin, turkey jowl kielbasa ribeye chicken jerky drumstick flank ham. Swine shankle pork belly kielbasa shoulder flank jowl, sirloin doner. Kevin tri-tip bresaola leberkas. Swine ball tip cow strip steak. Ham filet mignon pork chop, pork fatback andouille pork loin shoulder jowl swine strip steak turducken prosciutto rump.</p>

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="" />

    <p>Tongue tri-tip pastrami, shoulder rump pork belly ground round. Ham hock chuck leberkas doner, strip steak corned beef tri-tip capicola. Rump turkey ham sausage shankle. Flank shankle pork chop ham hock. Shankle venison kielbasa, pancetta swine beef ball tip t-bone bacon hamburger ground round ribeye flank. Turducken bacon bresaola, chicken kevin boudin ball tip strip steak filet mignon pork turkey shank ground round. Kielbasa fatback prosciutto pork chop, jerky ground round leberkas boudin ball tip beef shankle shoulder swine brisket.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="section-4">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/" alt="" />

    <p>Shoulder cow tenderloin chuck, pork chop jerky doner leberkas. Chuck sausage hamburger, kevin beef pork chop pork shoulder ground round ball tip turducken flank. Bresaola tri-tip meatloaf, salami venison tail pig shank shankle jowl sausage brisket cow biltong turducken. Swine turducken hamburger ball tip short loin prosciutto kevin jowl tri-tip. Doner meatloaf pork brisket.</p>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <button ng-click="toTheTop()">Take me back!</button> or <button ng-click="toSection3()">To section 3</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

index page

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="application">
  <head>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation for Apps</title>
    <link href="assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/templates.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/routes.js"></script>


    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #ebebeb;
    }
    body, button {
      font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    nav {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 30px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #fff;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    nav li, nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center
    }
    nav li, nav a {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    nav a {
      padding: 20px;
      color: #333;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
      background: #fff;
    }
    a.active {
      background: #00AC7F;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .wrap {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 50px 20px;
    }
    section {
      padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
    }
    footer {
      text-align: center;
    }
    button {
      font-size: 18px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 15px 30px;
      background: #00AC7F;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-frame vertical">
      <div class="grid-content shrink" style="padding: 0;">
        <ul class="primary condense menu-bar">
          <li><a ui-sref="home"><strong>Foundation for Apps</strong></a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="scroll">Scroll</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="group">Group</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ui-view autoscroll="true" class="grid-content">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

seems like foundation is setting overflow to be hidden on the grid-frame and grid-content has overflow-y:auto which causes the scroll functions not to work...